# к/ц becoming к/ч in Russian: chronology and reasons? Чередование к/ц и его переход в к/ч в русском: хронология и причины?

Tags: история-языка, slavic, фоносемантика

Читаем Иванова, "Историческая грамматика русского языка": "...в древнерусском языке противопоставление [ц'] и [ч'] на стыке корневой и флективной морфем могло иметь такой характер, что при помощи этого противопоставления различались разные словоформы, и поэтому неразличение [ц'] и [ч'] могло привести к развитию омонимов. Это наблюдалось, во-первых, в противопоставлении некоторых имен существительных с основой на -ц(ь) и однокорневых с ними притяжательных прилагательных на *ч(ь), исконно образованных с помощью суффикса [j] : заглць — запчь, корабльць —-корабльчь, льстьць — льстьчь, ловьць — ловьчь, отьць — отьчь, письць — письчь, пътица — пътича, старьць — старьчь, сълнь-це— сълньче, тельць — тельчь и др. Во-вторых, это обнаруживается в нескольких иных парах словоформ: куца („хижина") — куча, ниць— ничь („ничто"), тьмьница—тьмьнича (прилаг. от тьмьникъ— „тысячник") и др. Известно, что притяжательные прилагательные с древним суффиксом [j] были относительно рано утрачены древнерусским языком. Что же касается второй группы противопоставленных слов, то и здесь в истории языка один член этой пары также был утрачен в развитии русского языка"...

О древности чередования говорит и присутствие ц в словах "цветок" и "звезда" (ср. с польск. kwiat, gwiazda). Иванов объясняет это палатализацией заднеязычных, но в этом случае переход взрывных в свистящие после гласных переднего ряда (вторая палатализация) осуществлялся по закону гармонии гласных.

Как все-таки происходила палатализация и нет ли в этом финно-угорского субстрата?

The passage from Ivanov's Historical Grammar of Russian (1985) quoted above renders the old к/ц palatalisation subsequently becoming ц/ч. The fact of the alteration к/ц being the most old one is also confirmed by Polish cognates of kwiat and gwiazda for Russian  цветок & звезда. Ivanov explains all the alterations by palatalisation of velar consonants before front vowels, yet in such a case the transition from plosives to alveolar fricatives was happening according to vowel harmony (see Ivanov : 114).

How did the palatalisation actually happen and was there any Finno-Ugric substratum as a driving power of the process?

Comment: а почему вы смягчаете ц в окончаниях? и почему вы подозреваете именно финно-угорский субстрат?

Comment: Потому что это звательная форма и потому, что неразличение шипящих аффрикат характерно именно для финно-угорских языков (при преобладающем сингармонизме) плюс особенности древненовгородского диалекта (тоже, впрочем, неоднозначные).

Comment: Эти явления характерны для _всех_ славянских языков, даже для таких, как болгарский и словенский, никогда не контактировавших с уральскими народами.

Comment: 1. Где прародина славян (и примеры оных явлений из языков)?

Comment: 2. Когда появились эти явления?

Comment: @shabunc "ц" отвердел в основных русских говорах только в XVI веке, до этого был мягким.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, мне кажется, Вы методологически неверно подошли к вопросу - в том смысле, что Иванов принципиально ограничен в возможностях проработки фонетической истории форматом общего обзора. Начните хотя бы с "Исторической фонетики русского языка" В.В.Колёсова (версия 1980-го года есть у Ксаны К.), даже с первых страниц виден совершенно другой уровень изложения, на порядок глубже в плане методики фонологии и проработанных деталей.

Ну а далее, скорее всего, интересующие Вас аспекты уже далеко за пределами учебников и надо уходить в анализ научной периодики.

Comment: Благодарю. Ваш ответ - редкое и приятное исключение из большинства, с позволения сказать, "ответов" этого, так сказать, [censored] "сообщества"...